# Python - Requests module HTTP and HTTPS requests

Tags: python, http, https, get, python-requests

I wish to make a requests with the Python `requests` module. I have a large database of urls I wish to download. the urls are in the database of the form `page.be/something/something.html`

I get a lot of `ConnectionError`'s. If I search the URL in my browser, the page exists.

My Code:

```
if not webpage.url.startswith('http://www.'):
  new_html = requests.get(webpage.url, verify=True, timeout=10).text
```

An example of a page I'm trying to download is `carlier.be/categorie/jobs.html`. This gives me a `ConnectionError`, logged as below:

> Connection error, Webpage not available for
>   "carlier.be/categorie/jobs.html" with webpage_id "229998"

What seems to be the problem here? Why can't `requests` make the connection, while I can find the page in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

The `Requests` library requires that you supply a schema for it to connect with (the 'http://' part of the url). Make sure that every url has http:// or https:// in front of it. You may want a try/except block where you catch a `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema` and try again with `"http://"` prepended to the url.

Comment: So what would be a good code snippet for trying with http and https? catching ConnectionError and retrying with https doesn't seem like the good way to do it..

Comment: @SandervanDorsten I would process the url string before attempting to make the request. Are all of the urls supposed to go over http[s]? If that's the case, then you could even just check the first 4 characters of the string and if they're not http then prepend http:// or https:// to the url before making the request. The other obvious answer is a regular expression to determine if there is a format specifier in the string.